# Delete all files in directory with non utf-8 symbols

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x, filenames

I have a set of data, but I need to work only with `utf-8` data, so I need to delete all data with non-`utf-8` symbols.

When I try to work with these files, I receive:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 3062: character maps to <undefined> and UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 1576: invalid start byte
```

My code

```
class Corpus:
        def __init__(self,path_to_dir=None):
                self.path_to_dir = path_to_dir if path_to_dir else []


        def emails_as_string(self):
                for file_name in os.listdir(self.path_to_dir):
                        if not file_name.startswith("!"):
                                with io.open(self.add_slash(self.path_to_dir)+file_name,'r', encoding ='utf-8') as body:
                                        yield[file_name,body.read()]                        

        def add_slash(self, path):
                if path.endswith("/"): return path
                return path + "/"
```

I recive error here `yield[file_name,body.read()]` and  here`list_of_emails = mailsrch.findall(text)`, but when I work with utf-8 all great.

Comment: All ASCII characters are UTF-8 characters *too*.. Did you mean 'non-ASCII' perhaps?

Comment: When I work in my program with other symbols I receive   `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 3062: character maps to <undefined>` and `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 1576: invalid start byte`

Comment: Can you include your code too, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want to use the `errors='ignore'` argument on `bytes.decode`.  See http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-howto and http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode .for more info.

**Edit:**

Here's an example showing a good way to do this:

```
for file_name in os.listdir(self.path_to_dir):
    if not file_name.startswith("!"):
        fullpath = os.path.join(self.path_to_dir, file_name)
        with open(fullpath, 'r', encoding ='utf-8', errors='ignore') as body:
            yield [file_name, body.read()]
```

Using `os.path.join`, you can eliminate your `add_slash` method, and ensure that it works cross-platform.

Comment: So I suppose to add `.decode("utf-8", "ignore")` to my code  `yield[file_name,body.read()]` like this `yield[file_name,body.read().decode("utf-8", "ignore")]`? BTW, I still have error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 1576: invalid start byte`

Comment: No, since you're using `io.open`, you would use the `errors` argument in it instead, e.g. `io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')`.  As an aside, note that its generally a good idea to `os.path.join` to build up paths.  I would also suggest using the builtin `open` instead.  I'll update my answer to show an example of these.